# Showing that ∀x ∈ S ∀y ∈ E ( Q(x, y) → R(x) ) ≡ ∀x ∈ S (∃y ∈ E Q(x, y)) → R(x)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Q(x, y) := “Student x did exercise y in the book”

R(x) := “Student x gets an A in the class”

So my goal is to show that the following equivalency holds:

∀x ∈ S ∀y ∈ E ( Q(x, y) → R(x) ) ≡ ∀x ∈ S (∃y ∈ E Q(x, y)) → R(x)  (Note the exact parenthesis)

So the preceding statement would loosely translate to “If a student does at least one problem, they get an A in the class.”

However, everyone (classmates, TAs, professors, friends) disagrees with with my claim and, to the contrary, says that the statement the statement ∀x ∈ S ∀y ∈ E ( Q(x, y) → R(x) ) translates to:

"If a student does ALL exercises, they get an A in the class."

I'm going a little crazy over being told I'm incorrect and still not being convinced of it. Any help would be so greatly appreciated!

I have chosen very simple sets consisting of 1 student (me!) and only 2 book exercises, so the sets are small enough that I can write out the truth tables easily. I know that in order to complete my proof, I must show that it works for all sets of students and exercises, but it's pretty clear that it would also extend to all sets of Students and Exercises if I wanted to take up a few more pages.

1. Let the set S = {Nathan} (Note: S is supposed to be the set of students)
2. Let the set E = {1, 2} (Note: S is supposed to be the set of book exercises)
3. In English, I want to show that the statement ∀x ∈ S ∀y ∈ E ( Q(x, y) → R(x) ) translates to “If a student does at least one problem, they get an A in the class”
4. Let P be the following statement:
   ∀x ∈ S ∀y ∈ E ( Q(x, y) → R(x) )
5. In English, we may interpret this as “for all pairs of x and y, the implication “Q(x, y) → R(x)” holds.
6. Because the statement is true for all elements in S and S only contains 1 element, we can simply rewrite this as (book reference 1):
   ∀y ∈ E ( Q(Nathan, y) → R(Nathan) )
7. Because the implication holds for every y ∈ E, and there's only 2 elements in E, we can exhaustively write this as the conjunction of all possible Q(Nathan, y) (book reference 1): [ Q(Nathan, 1) → R(Nathan) ] ∧
   [ Q(Nathan, 2) → R(Nathan) ]

By truth table, I will show that the preceding statement is logically equivalent to the following statement:

[ Q(Nathan, 1) ∨ Q(Nathan, 2) ] → R(Nathan)

However, for the sake of fitting all my columns in one line, let:

A = Q(Nathan, 1)

B = Q(Nathan, 2)

R = R(Nathan)

So I need to show that the following logical equivalency holds: (A → R) ∧ (B → R) ≡ (A ∨ B) → R

```
A   B   R   A-->R   B-->R   (A-->R)^(B-->R) (A ∨ B) (A ∨ B) → R
T   T   T   T       T       T               T       T           
T   T   F   F       F       F               T       F           
T   F   T   T       T       T               T       T           
T   F   F   F       T       F               T       F           
F   T   T   T       T       T               T       T           
F   T   F   F       F       F               T       F           
F   F   T   T       T       T               F       T           
F   F   F   F       T       T               F       T
```

8. Because the truth tables for (A → R) ∧ (B → R) and (A ∨ B) → R are identical, they are logically equivalent.
9. ∴ The statement P can be written as: 
   ∀x ∈ S ∀y ∈ E ( Q(x, y) → R(x) ) ≡
   [ Q(Nathan, 1) → R(Nathan) ] ∧ [ Q(Nathan, 2) → R(Nathan) ] ≡
   [ Q(Nathan, 1) ∨ Q(Nathan, 2) ] → R(Nathan)
10. Now let Q be the following statement (I ultimately want to show that Q ≡ P):
    ∀x ∈ S (∃y ∈ E Q(x, y)) → R(x)
11. In English, we can interpret this as “For all students, if a student does at least one exercise they get an A in the class.”
12. Because the set S only has 1 element, we can  rewrite this as (book reference 2):
    (∃y ∈ Exercises Q(Nathan, y)) → R(Nathan)
13. Because the set E only contains only 2 elements, we can exhaustively write this as the disjunction of of all possible Q(Nathan, y) (book reference 2):
    (Q(Nathan, 1) ∨ Q(Nathan, 2)) → R(Nathan)
14. ∴ The statement Q can be written as: ∀x ∈ S (∃y ∈ E Q(x, y)) → R(x) ≡ (Q(Nathan, P1) ∨ Q(Nathan, P2)) → R(Nathan)

So per #9, I have shown that:
∀x ∈ S ∀y ∈ E ( Q(x, y) → R(x) ) ≡ [ Q(Nathan, 1) ∨ Q(Nathan, 2) ] → R(Nathan)

And per #13, I have shown that:
∀x ∈ S (∃y ∈ E Q(x, y)) → R(x) ≡ (Q(Nathan, 1) ∨ Q(Nathan, 2)) → R(Nathan)

15. ∴ ∀x ∈ S ∀y ∈ E ( Q(x, y) → R(x) ) ≡ ∀x ∈ S (∃y ∈ E Q(x, y)) → R(x)

So I have shown that (at least, for my simple example sets of S = {Nathan} and E = {1, 2}), the translation of the original statement ∀x ∈ S ∀y ∈ E ( Q(x, y) → R(x) ) can be written as:

```
∀x ∈ S              (∃y ∈ E Q(x, y))                →   R(x)
[ for all students ][ doing at least one problem ][ will get you an A in the class ]
```

So the question is: Am I correct or incorrect? And if I'm incorrect, where is my error?

I really, really appreciate any help! My question is very long only because prior attempts to “sum up” my argument have yielded unfruitful, so I wanted to show the entirety of my logic.

Book reference 1 (Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 7th edition page #41): http://books.google.com/books?id=55GaBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=%22When+all+the+elements+in+the+domain+can+be+listed%22&source=bl&ots=5mLN0LEs9c&sig=tADpIczl2xdN6fmTz9Zy0Lk3BqU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=I4VCVMfmIoWWyQScn4HICg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22When%20all%20the%20elements%20in%20the%20domain%20can%20be%20listed%22&f=false

Book reference 1 (Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 7th edition page #46): http://books.google.com/books?id=55GaBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=%22When+all+elements+in+the+domain+can+be+listed%22&source=bl&ots=5mLN0LEtig&sig=iwWaDDu8MfPesB3bOLFBcdsAcos&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5YVCVOP7Ns2ryATo-oDQBA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22When%20all%20elements%20in%20the%20domain%20can%20be%20listed%22&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. One way to see this is to look at the negation of the statement:

$$\begin{align*}
\neg\forall x\,\forall y\,\big(Q(x,y)\to R(x)\big)&\equiv\exists x\left(\neg \forall y\,\big(Q(x,y)\to R(x)\big)\right)\\
&\equiv\exists x\,\exists y\left(\neg\big(Q(x,y)\to R(x)\big)\right)\\
&\equiv\exists x\,\exists y\big(Q(x,y)\land\neg R(x)\big)\;.
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

This is true provided that there are a student $S$ and an exercise $e$ such that $S$ did $e$ but did not get an A in the class. Suppose, then, that $S$ was the only student in the class who did even one of the exercises, $S$ did only exercise $e$, and $S$ did not get an A in the class. Then $(1)$ is true, so the original statement

$$\forall x\,\forall y\,\big(Q(x,y)\to R(x)\big)$$

is false. If $S$ gets an A, however, $(1)$ becomes false: $Q(x,y)$ is false unless $x=S$ and $y=e$, in which case $R(x)=R(S)$ is true and $\neg R(S)$ is false. But $(1)$ is the negation of the original statement, which is therefore true in this setting — even though just one student has answered a question, and that student has answered only one question.

Everyone else appears to be thinking of the statement

$$\forall x\big(\forall y\,Q(x,y)\to R(x)\big)\;.$$

You can of course also let the class be $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and the set of exercises by $\{y_1,\ldots,y_m\}$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\forall x\,\forall y\,\big(Q(x,y)\to R(x)\big)&\equiv\forall x\Big(\big(Q(x,y_1)\to R(x)\big)\land\ldots\land\big(Q(x,y_m)\to R(x)\big)\Big)\\
&\equiv\forall x\Big(\big(\neg Q(x,y_1)\lor R(x)\big)\land\ldots\land\big(\neg Q(x,y_m)\lor R(x)\big)\Big)\\
&\equiv\forall x\Big(\big(\neg Q(x,y_1)\land\ldots\land\neg Q(x,y_m)\big)\lor R(x)\Big)\\
&\equiv\bigwedge_{i=1}^n\Big(\big(\neg Q(x_i,y_1)\land\ldots\land\neg Q(x_i,y_m)\big)\lor R(x_i)\Big)\;.
\end{align*}$$

For each student $x_i$ in the class this says

$$\big(\neg Q(x_i,y_1)\land\ldots\land\neg Q(x_i,y_m)\big)\lor R(x_i)\;,$$

i.e., either $x_i$ does no question at all, or $x_i$ gets an A in the class. If $x_i$ does even just one question, the only way for this to be true is for $x_i$ to get an A in the class. Thus, the original sentence does indeed say that each student who does at least one question gets an A in the class.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and the proof you provided! I wrote a similar proof (though using different logical equivalences, I think yours is more concise). I'll perhaps edit my post or add an answer showing my version in case it's helpful to anyone. I'll now be able to show these proofs to others and prove that my claim is in fact true!

Comment: @Nathan: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof I came up with that works for any finite set S and E that uses propositional expansion to show:
$\forall x \forall y (Q(x, y) \to R(x)) \equiv \forall x (\exists y Q(x, y) \to R(x))$

$\text{The set } S = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}
\\\text{The set } E = \{e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_m\}
$

$\begin{align*}\forall x \forall y (Q(x, y) \to R(x))\equiv
\\\forall y  (Q(x_1,  y) \to R(x_1)) \land && \text{propositional expansion of } \forall x
\\\forall y  (Q(x_2,  y) \to R(x_2)) \land
\\
\ldots \land
\\\forall y  (Q(x_n,  y) \to R(x_n))\equiv
\\
[Q(x_1, e_1) \to R(x_1)] \land \ldots \land [Q(x_1, e_m) \to R(x_1)] && \text {propositional expansion of } \forall y
\\ [Q(x_2, e_1) \to R(x_2)] \land \ldots \land [Q(x_2, e_m) \to R(x_2)]
\\ \ldots \land
\\ [Q(x_n, e_1) \to R(x_n)] \land \ldots \land [Q(x_n, e_m) \to R(x_n)]
\\\equiv
\\ [ (Q(x_1, e_1) \lor \ldots \lor Q(x_1, e_m)) \to R(x_1) ] \land && \text {note 1}
\\ [ (Q(x_2, e_1) \lor \ldots \lor Q(x_2, e_m)) \to R(x_2) ] \land
\\\ldots \land
\\ [ (Q(x_n, e_1) \lor \ldots \lor Q(x_n, e_m)) \to R(x_n) ] \equiv
\\ [ (\exists y Q(x_1, y) \to R(x_1)] \land   && \text{note 2}
\\ \ldots \land
\\ [ (\exists y Q(x_n, y) \to R(x_n)  ] && \text{note 3}
\\\equiv
\\\forall x (\exists y Q(x, y) \to R(x))
\end{align*}$

$\text{note 1: } (p_1 \to q) \land (p_2 \to q) \land \ldots \land  (p_n \to q) \equiv (p_1 \lor p_2 \lor \ldots \lor p_n) \to q
\\\text{note 2: } (P(x_1) \lor P(x_2) \lor \ldots \lor P(x_n)) \equiv \exists x P(x) \text{ (reverse propositional expansion)}
\\\text{note 3: } (P(x_1) \land P(x_2) \land \ldots \land P(x_n)) \equiv \forall x P(x) \text { (reverse propositional expansion)}
$